# Could more than one RFCOMM channels be created per time?

Tags: android, bluetooth, rfcomm

**Question:**

Could more than one RFCOMM channels be created per time?

**Testing method:**

Create connections from Cellphone(Samsung GALAXY S) to two terminals in the PC. PC has two different bluetooth devices(build-in and USB dongle) and using different COM ports, say COM1 and COM2.

Steps:

1. Testing each connection from cellphone to different bluetooth devices in PC using SPP, separately. ----> OK, cellphone could read what PC has sent in terminal using each bluetooth device. 
   This means PC, bluetooth device 1(BD1), bluetooth device 2(BD2) are working fine via SPP. Now, I am going to test two connections simultaneously.
2. Establish one connection, say cellphone-> BD1. ---> OK. Cellphone could read data from terminal 1 in PC using this connection.

   2.1 Establish another connection( cellphone -> BD2).  ---> OK. No exception be threw and the link was established successfully.

**PROBLEM:**

Once the second connection was established, what I typed in terminal 1 will be forward and received by second connection. In the other hand, no data will be received in connection 2 that was typed in terminal 2.

**Discussion**
I paste my bug report [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1RpgAZa0Emo_pD9W5eMBU_nPjNZ0s3svu1SZy_Sot58k). If I were right, the blue font part is the process that establish first connection, and the black font, under the blue font, is the process to establish second connection.

The reason I doubt that "more than one RFCOMM could be established" is in the bug report, I put it as bold fonts. We could see that both of them are using "**rc chan 1**", does this mean they ues the same RFCOMM??

Any recommend or suggestions are very very welcome!

Comment: There is a similar problem...posted as follow:http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=commitdiff;h=16fb88a673c41b93c5d57ccb28c2697e7d87701a

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem on `android 2.1`, try `android 2.2` and you will have 2 concurrent SPP/RFCOMM sessions working correctly (with none of that crosstalk). Im trying to get 3 and above concurrent connections up and running here on a Galaxy S phone (to 3 SPP slave devices) but it isnt connecting any more than 2 devices. Anyone know where this limit is being enforced? The straight BlueZ stack doesnt have this limitation.

thanks